# iOS 8 UISplitViewController is not working

Tags: ios8, ipad

I am launching my app to iOS 8 device trough test flight and everything works great except UISplitViewController. (I am running with XCODE 5.1.1)

It works fine in Landscape mode but having issue in protraitmode. Please see the below screenshots.

[image: SplitView issue in iOS8]

As of now I don't want to update my code base to Xcode 6 beta 6 because it has some strange issue for xibs and other areas as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you follow the following order:
1) Add child view controller
2) Add split view controller view as a subview of the container view
3) Set view controllers of the split view controller

If you reverse numbers 2 and 3, then this issue will appear in the scenario that your split view controller is **not** the root view controller of the app.